Weird Error Histogram in Neural Network Model at Matlab
I am developing a neural network in Matlab.
There are 22 numerical inputs (normalized between 0 to 1) and a single output (1 or 0). The dataset is based on the health information of patients.
When I run the script, it completes without any error but the Error Historgram looks really weird. All error values are accumulated far from zero.
How should I interprete this result?  I can share the script if needed.
Thank you
The Error

I tried to run with different activation functions, less (1 hidden layer) and more (3 hidden layers) and the result didnt change.

What are the values of your "targets"? It feels odd to have errors that are different than 0 or 1 when your output can only take those two values

thanks so much for response BillBokeey :) Yes, I have a 22x8000 input matrix comprising of both double and 1-0 columns and all normalized. And my output has simply prediction of a heart attack risk values as 1 - 0 (true-false). My script learns very fast (just in 5-6 epochs) and stops, returns this error histogram. I am not sure this graph Is correct.

Let me rephrase: Your outputs are only 0 or 1. The Errors that are calculated show values different than {-1,0 or 1}, which are the 3 unique values that should appear. It indicates that either your outputs, or the target values, take values that are not just 0 or 1. Check your datasets
